# Response Time of SQLite GROUP queries, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I would like to ask about the expected time of a GROUP query.

The truth is that I have a query with 10 conditions, retrieving data by that takes 166 ms, which is not a problem.

However, for the same query when I have the query and group by condition it takes 15358 ms or 4362 ms.

Are these number expected? Is there a way to improve the time consuming?

For example the following query takes 98150 ms

```
    (98150.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, 
patient_characteristic_gender AS patient_characteristic_gender FROM 
"characteristics" INNER JOIN "encounters" ON 
"encounters"."characteristic_id" = "characteristics"."id" INNER JOIN 
"encounters" "encounters_characteristics_join" ON 
"encounters_characteristics_join"."characteristic_id" = 
"characteristics"."id" INNER JOIN "conditions" ON 
"conditions"."encounter_id" = "encounters_characteristics_join"."id" WHERE
("encounters"."start_point" > '2012-01-01 00:00:00 +0100' AND 
"encounters"."end_point" < '2012-12-31 00:00:00 +0100') AND 
("conditions"."diagnosis" = 'Hospital Measures - AMI' AND 
"characteristics"."patient_characteristic_birthdate" <= '1997-07-31 
13:57:45 UTC' AND "encounters"."length_of_stay" <= 120 AND 
"encounters"."encounter" = 'Hospital Measures-Encounter Inpatient') GROUP 
BY patient_characteristic_gender
```

the number of patients/characteristics I have is around 3000

Using EXPLAIN I have the following:

```
(13008.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) 
AS count_all, patient_characteristic_gender 
AS patient_characteristic_gender 
FROM "characteristics" INNER JOIN "encounters" ON 
"encounters"."characteristic_id" = "characteristics"."id" INNER JOIN 
"encounters" "encounters_characteristics_join" ON 
"encounters_characteristics_join"."characteristic_id" = 
"characteristics"."id" INNER JOIN "conditions" ON 
"conditions"."encounter_id" = "encounters_characteristics_join"."id" 
 WHERE ("encounters"."encounter" = 'Hospital Measures-Encounter Inpatient'  AND 
"encounters"."length_of_stay" < 120 AND "conditions"."diagnosis" = 'Hospital Measures - AMI' AND 
"characteristics"."patient_characteristic_birthdate" > '18') 
GROUP BY patient_characteristic_gender

EXPLAIN for: SELECT "characteristics".* FROM "characteristics" INNER JOIN 
"encounters" ON "encounters"."characteristic_id" = "characteristics"."id"
 INNER JOIN "encounters" "encounters_characteristics_join" ON 
"encounters_characteristics_join"."characteristic_id" = 
"characteristics"."id" INNER JOIN "conditions" ON 
"conditions"."encounter_id" = "encounters_characteristics_join"."id" WHERE
 ("encounters"."encounter" = 'Hospital Measures-Encounter Inpatient' AND 
"encounters"."length_of_stay" < 120 AND "conditions"."diagnosis" = 
'Hospital Measures - AMI' AND 
"characteristics"."patient_characteristic_birthdate" > '18')
 GROUP BY patient_characteristic_gender

0|0|3|SEARCH TABLE conditions USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (diagnosis=?)
0|1|2|SEARCH TABLE encounters AS encounters_characteristics_join USING 
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0|2|0|SEARCH TABLE characteristics USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0|3|1|SCAN TABLE encounters
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY

{"female"=>1339, "male"=>1382}


schema:

 create_table "characteristics", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "ssn"
    t.date     "patient_characteristic_birthdate"
    t.string   "city"
end  
create_table "conditions", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "encounter_id"
    t.string   "diagnosis"
end

create_table "encounters", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "encounter"
    t.integer  "characteristic_id"
    t.integer  "length_of_stay"
end
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I have just edited it.

Comment: What's your schema? Do you have indexes on all of the columns you join on? Use `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`. Also please format your query to use newlines.

Comment: I do not use indexes that I create in migration. I just have a query of 4-5 conditions and I make a group by.

Comment: I updated it my question, I added the schema of these tables.